# Objective C - Calling a class method on the main thread?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, thread-safety, class-method

How can I call a `CLASS METHOD` on the main thread?
Something like:

```
[SomeClass performSelectorOnMainThread:staticMethod withObject:nil];
```

Please don't tell me to create a regular method to call this class method. That would be an obvious solution, but not clean.

Thanks

Comment: I would bet that you can achieve this with an NSInvocation. But I'm not quite sure, so just a comment.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
[SomeClass performSelectorOnMainThread:staticMethod withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Yes, `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` is not a class method.

Yes, it is an instance method on `NSObject`.

Yes, all Class objects are instances of `NSObject`. ([I'm not kidding!](http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2009/04/14/objc_explain_Classes_and_metaclasses.html))

---

You could also do:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  [SomeClass doClassyThingWithObject:object1 andDiddleyDoo:foo];
});
```

Comment: thanks, what if I am sending multiple parameters? lets say the method is [SomeClass staticMethodWithObject:a andOther:b orMore:c];

Comment: @aryaxt besides boxing the parameters into an `NSArray`, you'd have to use a different mechanism, like GCD (which I'ved edited my answer to show).

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:[SomeClass class] selector:@selector(SomeClass) object:nil];
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:operation];
```